# Python. Container file for different multimedia

Tags: python, file-io, multimedia

This is my problem.
I need to combine text, picture and video (any codec) into one file.
I know there is binary files. How would I go about packaging and reading the file.
For example, In the one file I store the text, then the png and then the video.

In another Python file I extract the files again and display as I please.
Regards,
Renier Engelbrecht

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) module - it creates a single file from arbitrary components.

Sample usage (Python 3):

```
import zipfile

# Write zip file
with zipfile.ZipFile("combined_file.zip", mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_STORED) as archive:
    archive.write("file_1.ext")
    archive.write("file_2.ext")

# Extract contents later
with zipfile.ZipFile("combined_file.zip", mode='r') as archive:
    archive.extractall()
```